# Not able to run drush in windows

Tags: php, drupal, drush

I have installed Drush-5.4-2012-06-04-Installer-v1.0.18.msi in the location C:\ProgramData\Drush by default. I run the program and moved to drupal working directory.

When I type drush  it is showing "drush is not recognized as an internal or external command " error. Do I need to configure anything before run? Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the path variable :

- right click on **computer**
- go to **properties**
- click **advanced system settings** then
- click on **environment variable**, then
- find the variable **path**
- and edit it

add this to end of the variable value **C:ProgramData\Propeople\Drush** and restart the drush, It should work.

Comment: One small correction: It should be 'C:\ProgramData\Propeople\Drush' instead of 'C:ProgramData\Propeople\Drush'. Otherwise, 'drush' was not working inside my project and was only working inside 'C:\ProgramData\Propeople\Drush'. It was throwing error "drush is not recoginized as internal or external command". Also, for me path is 'C:\ProgramData\Drush;'.

Answer (score 1):

Faced this problem while  i was installing drush with composer.

For anyone who have installed drush with composer, if this problem occures, You will have to set PATH variable as follows.

```
F:\Users\{YOUR-USERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\;
```

I did this and now my path variables are below.

```
F:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;F:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;F:\Program Files\Git\cmd;F:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;F:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;F:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\;
```

Be careful, Just don't copy paste above variables, you have to append drush path to existing variables.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal, you need to run `composer require drush/drush` command from the root project folder